# How to configure the alert whenever the primary Azure SQL Database goes down?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-monitoring, sql-azure-alerts

In Azure, how can you configure an alert or email notification when a SQL Server failover happened whenever you have setup a SQL server with Failover groups and failover policy is set to automatic?

So, can anyone suggest me how to configure the alert for the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference this blog: [In Azure, how can you configure an alert or notification when a SQL Server failover happened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161683/in-azure-how-can-you-configure-an-alert-or-notification-when-a-sql-server-failo/56161901#56161901)

CKelly found a way to script this in Azure using Automation Accounts > Runbook > using Powershell. A simple script like this should do it. Just need to figure out the run as account and trigger it by schedule or alert.:

```
function sendEmailAlert
{
    # Send email
}


function checkFailover
{
    $list = Get-AzSqlDatabaseFailoverGroup -ResourceGroupName "my-resourceGroup" -server "my-sql-server"

    if ( $list.ReplicationRole -ne 'Primary')
    { 
        sendEmailAlert
    }
}

checkFailover
```

Hope this helps.